# PHP - Ordering List of Directories by Modified Date

Tags: php

This is my current effort to get a list of files from an (Apache) server, and sort them into reverse modified order.

It works flawlessly, but why doesn't the reverse sort work with a list of directories? It lists them fine but doesn't order them.

```
<?php 
function getFiles(){
    $files=array();
    if($dir=opendir('.')){
        while($file=readdir($dir)){
            if (!in_array($file,array(".","..","index.php"))) {
                $files[]=$file;
            }
        }

        closedir($dir);

    }
    
    rsort($files); ##sort reverse modified
    return $files;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: We can't reproduce that. It would be helpful if you post the content (or just a part of it)of `$files` before and after using `rsort`.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "List of Directories by Modified Date"?

Comment: @b001ᛦ - The directories are named January, February, March etc.    The latest modified directory would be the current month, I would like that listed on top, followed by the others in reverse chronological order.

Comment: @WandererJoe please edit the question to include that info - the question is meaningless without it, as the code does not do what it says (`rsort($files); ##sort reverse modified` - this would only work if the file/dir names are e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD` formatted) and doesn't look to match your above description either.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFiles()
{
    $files = array();
    //put files in an array both have same modified time 
    $atSameTimes = [];
    if ($dir = opendir('.')) {
        while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
            if (!in_array($file, array(".", "..", "index.php"))) {
                if (isset($files[filemtime($file)])) {
                    if (isset($atSameTimes[filemtime($file)]) && is_array($atSameTimes[filemtime($file)])) {
                        $atSameTimes[filemtime($file)][] = $file;
                    } else {
                        $atSameTimes[filemtime($file)][] = $files[filemtime($file)];
                        $atSameTimes[filemtime($file)][] = $file;
                    }
                } else {
                    $files[filemtime($file)] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    
    $arr = array_replace_recursive($files, $atSameTimes);
    ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC); ##Sort an array in descending order and maintain index association
    //asort($arr); ##Sort an array in ascending order and maintain index association
    return $arr;
}
```

Sample output:

```
array(4) {
    [1577562574]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(15) "CONTRIBUTING.md"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "README.md"
      [2]=>
      string(11) "phpunit.xml"
    }
    [1607445739]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "LICENSE"
      [1]=>
      string(13) "composer.json"
      [2]=>
      string(12) "CHANGELOG.md"
    }
    [1612604942]=>
    string(19) "LoginController.php"
    [1622636168]=>
    string(19) "StoreController.php"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @tahabas - however those are FILES you are listing, my issue is that it's FOLDERS (directories) I need to list by modified date, latest on top.

Comment: @WandererJoe `opendir` doesn't distinguish between files and directories - there is no code change required to make the code in the answer output directories.

Comment: It's moot (because the question was unclear unfortunately) but that is a bit of a complex solution and a confusing output format (mixing flat and nested array values). Just building an array with `$files[filemtime($file) . $file] = $file;` and then reverse sorting the array would result in a (flat) array with the contents in the desired order.

Comment: yes you’r right my answer is a bit confusing that might be better and if only directories wanted that can be checked in loop with is_dir() function.